# Two ArrayList are having same reference

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //added 0-9 to ArrayList
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        a.add(new Integer(i));

        //initialize the Iterator
        ListIterator<Integer> i = a.listIterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        System.out.print(i.next());

        System.out.print(" ");

        b = a;
        Collections.shuffle(a);
        //initialized the iterator again and print all the elements
        i = b.listIterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        System.out.print(i.next());
    }
}

//Output : 012345678 528430617
```

As per above code if I am shuffling ArrayList a then ArrayList b also updates
So how can I see even after updating a it should not update b

Answer (score 4):

This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
b = a;
```

The values of both `b` and `a` are *references*, not *objects*. The above statement simply copies the value of `a` to `b`, so now both variables have the same values, referring to the same object.

Another demonstration of the same point:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder y = x;
x.append("foo");
System.out.println(y); // Will print foo
```

*All* objects in Java work like this. The value of an expression is *always* a primitive value or a reference, *never* an object.

If you want to create a second object, you need to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a copy of `a`:

```
b = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
```

That will create a new `ArrayList` and add all of `a`'s elements into it.

Comment: is this method better or using clone function of ArrayList?

Comment: I prefer to use this instead of `clone()` because `clone()` returns `Object` (which then requires a cast to `ArrayList<Integer>`).